# Как реализовать, так скажем резиновый по высоте UITextView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitextview, uiview

Я сделал UIView который расположен в самом низу, и если допустим появляется клавиатура, UIView реагирует и поднимается вместе с клавой -- Сделано это все на константах и неким простым кодом, который задает height клавиатуры константе, дабы поднять этот чудесный UIView.

Вопрос в следующем, как сделать так, чтобы если я создал новую строку расширился по высоте сам UITextView как и UIView, и это все дело автоматически прижалось к клавиатуре без каких-либо отступов (как на скриншоте).

[image: ios]

Answer (score 1):

1) Отключаешь скролл у textView.

2) В делегате (в методе shouldChangeTextInRange) в блоке dispatch_after ставишь размер textView по содержимому (метод sizeThatFits).

3) Ставишь высоту textView.superview равной высоте textView.

4) Прижимаешь textView.superview к низу vc.view (если она уже сжата под клавиатуру).

5) Таблицу сжимаешь до оставшейся высоты.